# show customize bootstrap modal after 5 minute in page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to show automatically bootstrap modal in my page after 5 minute from page fully loaded time and user can not be able to close modal what should i do?

also i use default modal code like below

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
 labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
 <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    ...
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI, if you just add a modal over the page content, a user that knows how to use the "Inspect Element" would be able to easily get rid of your modal and keep doing whatever he/she was doing on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout after page load

```js
setTimeout(()=> {
    $('#exampleModal').modal({
  backdrop: 'static' , keyboard: false
})
} , 30000)
```